# Modify MySQL internal date format

Tags: mysql, date, format

A date datatype in mySQL is of the format yyyy-mm-dd. I want it to store a date as dd-mm-yyyy.

All answers showed how to display date in a particular format. However I want to modify the format in which MySQL stores dates.

Is there anyway I can acheive this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that. It makes no sense whatso ever.

Comment: Why do care how the data is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the MSQL date storage format. You can use `DATE_FORMAT()` for displaying it in your display format.

Edit as per your comment:-

```
 INSERT INTO useless_table (id, date) VALUES(
        1, STR_TO_DATE('06/08/2013', '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Comment: I want to use insert query and type ddmmyyyy rather than doing conversions to yyyymmdd everytime before I insert.

Comment: Yes it worked.
Unfortunately it does not answer my original question to change the way MySQL stores date. Because now, I have to do formatting every time I have to insert or read any value everytime. MySQL still storing date as YYYY-MM-DD but I want DD-MM-YYYY to be stored for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the way the DB store date.

Those are are stored as YYYY-MM-DD in order to use [lexicographic order](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d1f8/1) to sort date. Any other format would lose that property, and thus the DB server wouldn't be able to efficiently sort dates.

As you apparently already have been told, you might change the date format in the `SELECT` query. If you *really really* want store date using some other format, you will probably have to use a `CHAR(10)` columns.

If you go that way, you will be able to search for equality in that column. But not to sort by date. Neither to find a date in a given range.

Comment: Hmm, That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Dates and times are stored in the SQL database in an internal format native to the SQL engine, the first 4 bytes stores the number of days since SQL Server's epoch (1st Jan 1900). The second 4 bytes stores the number of milliseconds after midnight.

You shouldn't be concerned with how the date is stored.  You can retrieve the date (or date/time) in whatever format you like (or need).

Comment: Problems arised when trying to use insert query with ddmmyyyy

Comment: You need to format it on the insert then ... try this:
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the column's name is time, you can use the following sql

```
SELECT YEAR(time) as year, MONTH(time) as month, DAY(time) as day FROM table
```

Then, just do as you wish.